# RStudio - Compression when saving environment

Tags: r, save, compression, rstudio

Is there a way to set the options in [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) such that when it saves my environment to an `.RData` file, it doesn't use compression by default?

I guess I can manually use `save.image()` to do this (with or without compression as needed), but I'd prefer [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) to do this for me if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe modify the save function by using a .Rprofile ? Check this : https://www.r-bloggers.com/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain that RStudio always uses the standard code to save the image, but plain R uses the `save.image` function to save, and you can set the defaults for the arguments `version`, `ascii`, `compress`, and `safe` to that function using

```
options(save.image.defaults = args)
```

where `args` is a list giving the defaults you want.  So you'd want

```
options(save.image.defaults = list(compress = FALSE))
```

A quick test suggests that this works in RStudio too.

However, I have to point out that using `save.image` is generally a bad idea.  You should save particular objects that need saving, but wholesale saving can cause confusion when R starts up with unexpected contents in the global environment.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it works in RStudio - I've added options(save.image.defaults = list(compress = FALSE)) to the script I'm using and now RStudio will save an uncompressed image upon quitting, which is what I wanted.